# Is it a good practice to overload math functions in namespace std in c++

Tags: c++, std, overloading, cmath

I am writing a C++ class which represents an arithmetic type (a c++ wrapper around [mpfr](http://www.mpfr.org/)), and I'd like to support some functions found in <cmath> (I'll take std::sqrt as an example).

So I have the following class:

```
namespace ns
{
  class MyClass
  {
      /* ... */
      public:
      friend MyClass sqrt(const MyClass& mc);
  };
}
```

And I can use it this way:

```
MyClass c;
/* ... */
MyClass d = ns::sqrt(c);
MyClass e = sqrt(c); // Apparently I don't have to specify ns::
```

But I cannot use it this way:

```
MyClass f = std::sqrt(c);
```

Compiler (g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5)) error is: "no matching function for call to sqrt(ns::MyClass&)".

This is normal, but it's a problem to me. I need this to be valid, because MyClass is supposed to be used into existing template functions (that I'm not supposed to modify). For example:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T a)
{
    /* ... */
    T c = std::sqrt(a);
    /* ... */
}
int main()
{
    func<float>(3);
    func<MyClass>(MyClass(3));
    /* ... */
}
```

The following piece of code actually resolve my problem:

```
namespace std
{
  using ns::sqrt;
}
```

But adding things into the std namespace seems very unnatural to me. I am afraid to run into unexpected troubles later, doing this.

Is it safe ? If not, why ?

Is there a better alternative ?

Comment: I think it is not safe if not tested. Said this, I think if your implementation seems better why not propose it to the standard? They'll even test some data sets you may have not though of.

Comment: @Claudiordgz Presumably it's for multi-precision integers, so its purpose is orthogonal to that of `std::sqrt` which is for native types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s not safe, because it’s not legal (§17.6.4.2.1):

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

So you may add specialisations for your own types. You may *not* add overloads (or indeed anything else).

Your current code is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: For something like `sqrt`, would it be legal to add template functions that mimic overloading? This template will match only on type `X` and therefore is 'almost' the same as an overload for `X`. E.g. (inside namespace `std`), do the following: `template<typename T> auto sqrt(T x) -> typename std:: enable_if< std:: is_same<T,X>::value, X > :: type { /* do square root and return */; }`

Comment: @Aaron That’s an overload. You are not allowed to *add* function templates (= overload), you’re only allowed to specialise *existing* templates.

Comment: The formal proof my fears were correct. Accepted answer because you're quoting the standards. Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

Adding stuff to namespace `std` is prohibited by the standard. The correct way to tackle this problem is normally seen with `swap` (that is available in the `std` namespace, but that can be specialized by user-defined types to work more efficiently): when a template function needs to use e.g. `sqrt`, it will do

```
using std::sqrt;
a=sqrt(b);
```

This way, for "regular" types it will use `std::sqrt` ("taken in" by the `using` statement), while for your type your overload will prevail due to [Koenig lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) (which, incidentally, is the reason of the behavior you observed at `// Apparently I don't have to specify ns::`).

Comment: Apparently, the std::sqrt symbol is already in global namespace (no need to "using std::sqrt;").

Comment: `sqrt` should be in the global namespace only if you include `<math.h>` instead of `<cmath>`.

Comment: Well, I don't include <math.h> and I still have a global symbol sqrt (made a standalone test). It seems to be the pure C sqrt function. I don't understand why it happens, but it makes your answer relevant too

Comment: @doomyster this is a common problem of real-world C++ implementations. So common in fact, that it has been explicitly allowed since C++11 that the implementation may (or may not) declare C functions outside of namespace `std` even for `cmath`, `cstdio` and their brothers.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative, within generic functions, is to do this:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T a)
{
    using std::sqrt;

    /* ... */
    T c = sqrt(a);
    /* ... */
}
```

And defining additional things into the std-namespace is not safe in general (and not strictly legal).

Answer (score 1):

Not so good an idea to put it in std namespace.

Since you have your own namespace, you could import sqrt into your namespace and add specialized `sqrt` functions:

```
namespace ns {
  using std::sqrt;
  MyClass sqrt(const MyClass &)
}

ns::sqrt(...);
```