# Is it valid to pass non-arithmetic types as arguments to cmath functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14, cmath

Given the following user-defined type `S` with a conversion function to *double*:

```
struct S
{
   operator double() { return 1.0;}
};
```

and the following calls to [cmath](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) functions using the type `S`:

```
#include <cmath>

void test(S s) {
   std::sqrt(s); 
   std::log(s); 
   std::isgreater(s,1.0);
   std::isless(s,1.0);
   std::isfinite(s) ;
}
```

This code compiles with `gcc` using `libstdc++` (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/15CSejElegZAf85f)*) but with `clang` using `libc++` it generates errors for several of the calls (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ImDK79QNvnVG0hnn)*) with the following error for [isgreater](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isgreater):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'isgreater'
   std::isgreater(s,1.0);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _A1 = S, _A2 = double]
std::is_arithmetic<_A1>::value &&
^
```

and similar errors for [isless](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isless) and [isfinite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite), so `libc++` expects the arguments for those calls to be [arithmetic types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) which `S` is not, we can confirm this by going to the source for [libc++ cmath header](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/0b6f8ed1c772afbdb2c28451e67ac5ee7b6092fe/include/cmath). Although, the requirement for arithmetic types is not consistent across all the `cmath` functions in `libc++`.

So the question is, is it valid to pass non-arithmetic types as arguments to `cmath` functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**

According to the standard it is valid to pass non-arithmetic types as arguments to `cmath` functions but defect report `2068` argues the original intent was that `cmath` functions should be restricted to arithmetic types and it appears possible using non-arithmetic arguments will eventually be made ill-formed. So although technically valid using non-arithmetic types as arguments seems questionable in light of defect report `2068`.

**Details**

The [cmath](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math) header is covered in the draft standard section `26.8` *[c.math]* provides an additional *float* and *long double* overload for the each function defined in [math.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math) that takes a *double* argument and further, paragraph `11` provides for *sufficient overloads* and says:

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:
>
> 1. If any argument corresponding to a double parameter has type long double, then all arguments corresponding to double parameters are
>      effectively cast to long double.
> 2. Otherwise, if any argument corresponding to a double parameter has type double or an integer type, then all arguments corresponding to
>      double parameters are effectively cast to double.
> 3. Otherwise, all arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to float.

**This seems valid in C++11**

In C++11  section `26.8` *[c.math]* does not include any restrictions disallowing non-arithmetic arguments to `cmath` functions. In each case from the question we have an overload available which takes *double* argument(s) and these should be selected via [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

**Defect report 2086**

But for C++14 we have [defect report 2086: Overly generic type support for math functions](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2086), which argues that the original intent of section `26.8` *[c.math]* was to limit `cmath` functions to be valid only for *arithmetic types*, which would mimic how they worked in *C*:

> My impression is that this rule set is probably more generic as
>   intended, my assumption is that it is written to mimic the C99/C1x
>   rule set in 7.25 p2+3 in the "C++" way [...] (note that C constraints
>   the valid set to types that C++ describes as arithmetic types, but see
>   below for one important difference) [...]

and says:

> My current suggestion to fix these problems would be to constrain the
>   valid argument types of these functions to arithmetic types.

and reworded section `26.8` paragraph `11` to say (*emphasis mine*):

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:
>
> 1. If any **arithmetic** argument corresponding to a double parameter has type long double, then all **arithmetic** arguments corresponding to
>      double parameters are effectively cast to long double.
> 2. Otherwise, if any **arithmetic** argument corresponding to a double parameter has type double or an integer type, then all **arithmetic**
>      arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to
>      double.
> 3. Otherwise, all **arithmetic** arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to **<s>are effectively cast to</s> have type** float.

**So this is invalid in C++14?**

Well, despite the intent it looks technically to still be valid as argued in this comment from the discussion in [libc++ bug report:  incorrect implementation of isnan and similar functions](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18218#c8):

> That may have been the intent, but I don't see any way to read the
>   standard's wording that way. From the example in comment#0:
>
> ```
> std::isnan(A());
> ```
>
> There are no arguments of arithmetic type, so none of the bullets in
>   26.8/11 apply. The overload set contains 'isnan(float)', 'isnan(double)', and 'isnan(long double)', and 'isnan(float)' should
>   be selected.

So, the rewording by `DR 2086` of paragraph *11* does not make it ill-formed to call the *float*, *double* and *long double* overloads available otherwise with non-arithmetic arguments.

**Technically valid but questionable to use**

So although the C++11 and C++14 standard do not restrict `cmath` functions to arithmetic arguments `DR 2068` argues the intent of `26.8` paragraph `11` was to restrict `cmath` functions to take only arithmetic arguments and apparently intended to close the loophole in C++14, but did not provide strong enough restrictions.

It seems questionable to rely on a feature which could become ill-formed in a future version of the standard. Since we have implementation divergence any code that relies on passing non-arithmetic arguments to `cmath` functions for those cases is non-portable and so will be useful only in limited situations. We have an alternative solution, which is to explicitly cast non-arithmetic types to arithmetic types, which bypasses the whole issue, we no longer have to worry about the code becoming ill-formed and it is portable:

```
std::isgreater( static_cast<double>(s) ,1.0)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As Potatoswatter points out using unary `+` is also an option:

```
std::isgreater( +s ,1.0)
```

**Update**

As T.C. points out in C++11 it can be argued that `26.8` paragraph `11` bullet `3` applies since the argument is neither *long double*, *double* nor an integer and should therefore the arguments of type `S` should be cast to *float* first. Note, as indicated by the defect report `gcc` never implemented this and as far I know neither did `clang`.

Comment: Arguably, the C++11 wording requires `s` be cast to `float`, since its type is neither `long double` nor `double` nor an integer type.

Comment: @T.C. I kept debating that one, but yes it is arguable. Note, neither `libc++` nor `libstdc++` implement it that way.

Comment: `+ s` may be considered idiomatic too.

Comment: @Potatoswatter that is a fair point, I personally prefer to use more explicit cast then falling back on using unary `+` or old style C casts but I know many will argue that it saves typing and is not as ugly.