# Overloading STL function

Tags: c++, stl, overloading

I have a code like this:

```
   set<array<int, 3>> s;
   int ar[3] = {1,2,3};
   s.insert(ar);
   auto it = s.find(ar);
```

And the message of IDE that `no instance of overloaded function insert/find`. If I use `std::array` it is ok, `::insert` and `::find` work in the same way.
But what if i wanna use these C arrays `T[N]` or find function with `std::array` in set should return iterator if two of three elements equal. Or `set::insert` will not insert a new array if it is a permutation of exist, I mean `s.insert({1,2,3})` - already added, `s.insert({3,2,1})` - return iterator on `{1,2,3}`.

The question is how to overload STD functions? Not in this code especially but in general? Any link or real code example welcome.  May be its a really simple question for experienced programmers) but there are a lot of examples of operator overloading, but no for STL. Thanks.

Comment: Why not declare an `array<int,3> ar{ {1,2,3} }` in your function instead of an `int ar[3]`?

Comment: Yeap, it works that way. But i want to understand some things about overloading STL at all.

Comment: Note that the days of STL are [gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library). It has now become a part of the standard library.

Comment: We can use the unordered map/set container with specialized version of hashing
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: @Evg -- unfortunately, "STL" now stands for STandard Library.

Comment: @PeteBecker, should "STL" be used to refer to the standard library nowadays?

Comment: @Evg -- "should .. be used"? No. "is widely used"? Yes. :-(

Comment: @Evg it is informative :) Before i`v read this i think STL - always mean STandart Library of C++. All what in namespace std. But it have another value.Full time holy war about this.. But in question i mean standard library.

Comment: @AlexeyChicherin, BTW, the author of STL is russian-american programmer Alexander Stepanov. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot declare additional overloads for a member function of a class outside the class definition. The language does not provide syntax for it. Since you can't modify the class definition in the standard library headers, you cannot add additional overloads to them either.

---

Free functions in the `std` namespace may not be overloaded. There is syntax for it (the same way any overloads of free functions work), but doing so causes undefined behavior, because it is explicitly forbidden in the standard, see [[namespace.std]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.std#1).

---

What is usually (exceptions apply) allowed is to define *template specializations* for entities in the `std` namespace, but only if the specialization depends on a user-defined type and not for member functions, member function templates or member class templates. See the rest of the quoted and following paragraph linked above.

A common example where specialization inside the `std` namespace is used is `std::hash` for use as hash function in unordered associative containers:

```
struct my_type {
    //...
};

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<my_type> {
        auto operator()(my_type const& x) const noexcept {
            //...
        }
    };
}
```

But even something like that is not allowed if `my_type` is replaced by `int*`, `int[3]` or `std::array<int, 3>` or anything similar, because there is no dependence on a user-declared type.

---

If you want to make a `std::array` from a built-in array, you will be able to use `std::to_array` in C++20:

```
set<array<int, 3>> s;

int ar[3] = {1,2,3};

s.insert(std::to_array(ar));

auto it = s.find(std::to_array(ar));
```

Before C++20, you might have the function available as `std::experimental::to_array` in `#include<experimental/array>` or you can define it yourself (from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array); requires `#include<type_traits>`, `#include<utility>` and `#include<cstddef>`):

```
namespace detail {

template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
constexpr std::array<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N>
    to_array_impl(T (&a)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return { {a[I]...} };
}

}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N> to_array(T (&a)[N])
{
    return detail::to_array_impl(a, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Comment: Thats because i cant upvote answer. Not enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

About the other question - about permutations, i.e., that you want your set to find iterator to `{1,2,3}` when you look for a permutation of it.

Technically, you can do 2 things:

(1) make a specialized comparison operator for which permutations are equivalent. Or make a class that wraps `std::array` and implement its comparison operators this way.

(2) (preferred) simply sort your array before adding it to set and/or searching for it.

If you need its elements in original order, then I recomend to make utility class that contains both the original array and sorted version that it uses for comparisons.

If you also want to be able to add option for having multiple original while returning the exact one when it exists... then its more complicated. It can be done with some composite functions.

Comment: Thanks! Utility class i think the best decision in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @walnut said, you cannot declare additional overloads for a member function of a class outside the class definition. Other than encapsulate your own int<3> class, there is another work around - operator << override.

```
set<array<int, 3>>& operator << (set<array<int, 3>>& s, int ar[3])
{
    array<int,3> ar2 { ar[0], ar[1], ar[2] };
    s.insert(ar2);

    return s;
}
```

It looks weird, but easy to use.

Now you can do this

```
set<array<int, 3>> s;
int ar[3] = {1,2,3};

s << ar;
```

However, if there is a bunch of functions you want to use in set against int[3] against array, It is better to define your own class / struct.

```
template <class T, int arsize>
struct MyFixedArray
{
    T ar[arsize];
    MyFixedArray(T _ar[arsize]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arsize; ++i)
            ar[i] = _ar[i];
    };
    operator array<T, arsize>() const {
        array<T, arsize> _ar;
        for (int i = 0; i < arsize; ++i)
            _ar[i] = ar[i];

        return _ar;
    };
};
```

and now you can use it freely everwhere

```
MyFixedArray<int, 3> myar(ar);

s.insert(myar);
auto it = s.find(myar);
```

Comment: I`m trying to compile and it works:) Сould you clarify about the insert operation here? I mean if we using is set<int>,  set::insert trying to find existing element, compare by key value, if there is no equal insert new element of set, if equal return iterator. If it set<std::array<int,n>>  set::insert overloaded in standard library, and trying to find full equality of each[n] position in array and make the same. But here we pass the value of MyFixedArray class. How this conversion to array<int,n> happen? If will be two varaible like T ar[arsize] and T ar2[arsize]; Which will be used?

Comment: operator array<T, arsize>() const { … } is the conversion operator override. When you use set<array<int, 3>>::insert, it is looking for array<int, 3> as a parameter, but you passed in MyFixedArray<int, 3>. It has a conversion operator to array<int, 3>, so it will be called to do the conversion, then pass to insert.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that C++ gives you the right to do so. For more information, you may get this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22701397/6941952) useful in your case.
I hope that helps your problem.

Comment: Thank you. As i understand this : "A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template..."  mean that [std::set::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) - have template version and i can create specialization?, and [std::set::insert] (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) - do not have.  Of course i can create new container and add in it any features, but without c++ STL perfomance

Comment: @AlexeyChicherin, you can't. The template version of `.find` is there to support transparent comparators. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators).